# Why didn't Kotlin follow Java syntax?

Tags: kotlin

I'm in the process of learning Kotlin as an Android developer!

Out of curiosity, why didn't the JetBrains guys follow the Java style syntax (where they could have), and **made it easier on developers to learn Kotlin**?

For example, defining a simple function in Kotlin:

```
fun simpleFunc(x: Int): Int {

// do stuff

}
```

Why didn't they do:

```
fun Int simpleFunc(Int x) {

// do stuff

}
```

I would appreciate hearing your opinion on this

Comment: It follows the scala syntax, another popular JVM language.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As mentioned in the [Kotlin FAQ](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/faq.html), Kotlin's syntax makes it more natural to omit type declarations when they can be inferred by the compiler (which isn't supported by Java). Also, from our experience with Kotlin, we see no evidence that Kotlin's type declaration syntax presents a difficulty for people learning Kotlin.

(Note that your suggested syntax is also different from Java, so it's not clear why you think it would be easier to learn.)

Comment: I'm not suggesting that Kotlin is hard to learn. But, still was wondering if we could have avoided learning YET another new syntax and still enjoy all of Kotlin's features

Comment: It may have been possible to shoehorn Kotlin's features into the Java syntax using annotations, but the end result would have looked far more ugly than Kotlin and wouldn't have been easier to learn.

Comment: @yole that's grt,but when programmers use an IDE like Intelij, they still think about types first to use automatically generated name . Its all about trade-offs. Isn't it?

Comment: @KrupalShah This hasn't been my experience. Note that the IntelliJ IDEA Kotlin plugin can offer completion suggestions for variable names and types together (e.g. for parameter names).

Answer (score 3):

Java is like a coffee, and Kotlin means that coffee with a little bit sugar in there. In some cases, Kotlin does increase the efficiency and make the programming more enjoyable.

Comparing with Java, Kotlin is more effective and actually can work with Java pretty well.
Check the example in that picture here about Safe Calls on the official kotlinlang.org,

[image]

In Chains, when there's a **null** value，you need to use if function to determine whether the value is **null**，but there's only one sentence method needed for Kotlin.

Plus, when you are using Gradle daemon and Smart Compilation，Kotlin shows a faster compile speed than Java.

[image]

the horizontal axis means ten consecutive incremental builds with one core file changed.

You can see that the Gradle daemon still takes two or three runs to warm up, but after that the performance of both languages is very similar. With no changes, Java takes 4.6 seconds per warm build, while Kotlin averages 4.5 seconds. When we change a file that isn’t used by any other files, Java requires an average of 7.0 seconds to do a warm build, and Kotlin clocks in at 6.1. And finally, when we change a file that is imported by many other files in the project, Java requires 7.1 seconds to do an incremental build once the Gradle daemon is warmed up, while Kotlin averages 6.0 seconds.

Citations: 1. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html

2. https://medium.com/@johnkorly/kotlin-vs-java-performance-drill-down-which-to-choose-2514bdf91916

Comment: I like the answer, it's got my support, but that graph is terrible and can be misinterpretted easily. What's the horizontal axis even measuring? We could be testing the compilation time of two "5kB code samples, 10kB samples, 15kB samples, etc..." where each one does completely different things, but are exactly 5kB, 10kB, 15kB, etc.

Comment: I did ten trails and the horizontal axis means ten consecutive incremental builds with one core file changed.

Comment: You can see that the Gradle daemon still takes two or three runs to warm up, but after that the performance of both languages is very similar. With no changes, Java takes 4.6 seconds per warm build, while Kotlin averages 4.5 seconds. When we change a file that isn’t used by any other files, Java requires an average of 7.0 seconds to do a warm build, and Kotlin clocks in at 6.1. And finally, when we change a file that is imported by many other files in the project, Java requires 7.1 seconds to do an incremental build once the Gradle daemon is warmed up, while Kotlin averages 6.0 seconds.

Comment: Now this is just the data lover in me, but I'm interested: What sort of code is being compiled? It'd be neat to know how much of the JVM's instruction set is being used and to see the performance delta of specific functions which end up compiling differently, but that's way outside this question's scope.

Answer (score 2):

The kotlin team describes [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/faq.html#why-have-type-declarations-on-the-right) why the type declarations (like in your example) are on the right:

> **Why have type declarations on the right?**
>
> We believe it makes the code more readable. Besides, it enables some nice syntactic features. For instance, it is easy to leave type annotations out. Scala has also proven pretty well this is not a problem.